# Express.js routing: optional splat param?

Tags: node.js, express

I have a route that looks like this:

```
app.all('/path/:namedParam/*splat?',function(req,res,next){
  if(!req.params.length){
    // do something when there is no splat
  } else {
    // do something with splat
  }
});
```

however, this doesn't work - if I call `path/foo/bar` it hits the route, but if I call `path/foo`, it doesn't.

Is it possible to have an optional splat param, or do I have to use a regex to detect this?

**Edit**:

to be clearer, here are the requirements I'm trying to achieve:

- the first and second params are **required**
- the first param is static, the second is a named param.
- any number of *optional* additional params can be appended and still hit the route.

Comment: what are you trying to do? if you don't need to know splat, just do `'/path/:firstParam/*'`. If you need it, do `'/path/:firstParam/:secondParam?/*'`.

Comment: I'm looking to have the splat be optional - the first example you gave would not match `/path/foo`, (that is what my route originally looked like before I wanted an optional splat). Additionally, in your second example, adding the splat actually negates the optional second param - `/path/foo` will not match your second pattern (neither will `/path/foo/bar` for that matter...) - one of the more annoying parts of express' router.

Comment: personally i would just go for `/path/:firstParam` and `/path/:firstParam/:secondParam/` as two separate routers with a shared controller. no need to make your urls confusing

Comment: Having `n` endpoints is necessary for the design of the app - I'm not just routing to 1-3 params, it can be any number, so having a limit on number of params is not an option (sure, I could create 10 endpoints, but having express do that work isn't any better than doing it in a route). I can use a regex route to solve my problem (what I'm doing now), but I was hoping to have a readable option.

Comment: its amazing that the devs didn't think to simply use parenthesis for named optional params. ie `/path/:param(/:otherOptionalParam)`

Answer (score 115, accepted):

This works for /path and /path/foo on express 4, note the `*` before `?`.

```
router.get('/path/:id*?', function(req, res, next) {
    res.render('page', { title: req.params.id });
});
```

Comment: Note that while this does work, if you visit `/path/foo/bar/bazzle`, `req.params.id` will equal `foo`, and `req.params[0]` will equal `/bar/bazzle`, which may trip some people up. A cleaner solution may be to define the path as `/path/*?`, which in express 4 will set `req.params[0]` to `foo/bar/bazzle`, which is probably closer to what you're looking for.

Comment: you're better off url encoding your optional parameter - allowing anything with slashes means you will run into conflicts down the road if you want to add a path like app.get('path/:required1/:required2/:optional?*', handler)

Comment: @Jesse Any way to make the last part required? For example I want to match `/path/foo/bar` but *not* `/path/foo`. I tried `'/path/:id/*` but `*` seems to match empty string as well.

Answer (score 77):

I just had the same problem and solved it. This is what I used:

```
 app.get('path/:required/:optional*?', ...)
```

This should work for `path/meow`, `path/meow/voof`, `path/meow/voof/moo/etc`...

It seems by dropping the `/` between `?` and `*`, the last `/` becomes optional too while `:optional?` remains optional.

Comment: Cool! I just tested this (in express 3.0.0, haven't tested in 2.x) and it works. This is definitely cleaner than my RegEx hack.

Comment: Do you know where I can read more about these predefined keywords?

Comment: In express 4.0x this does not appear to work anymore

Comment: @chris answered this for express 4 - since that's the latest, I moved the accepted answer to his.

Comment: Ran into a weird error using this, for numbers with zero in it, express will cut it off. For example /:id where id=904, req.params.id = 9 and req.params.0=04 (express dumps this rest here for some reason). Chris's answer fixes this

Comment: Is this missing a closing quote or is the `, ...` part of the string?

Comment: Thanks @jocull, amazing no one noticed until now... Fixed

Comment: This, `?*`, worked best for my needs because `*?` does not respect `path/meow`; it only respects `path/meow/xyz`

Answer (score 18):

Will this do what you're after?

```
app.all('/path/:namedParam/:optionalParam?',function(req,res,next){
  if(!req.params.optionalParam){
    // do something when there is no optionalParam
  } else {
    // do something with optionalParam
  }
});
```

More on Express' routing here, if you haven't looked: http://expressjs.com/guide/routing.html

Comment: This solution would match `/path/foo/bar`, but not `/path/foo/bar/baz` - the `*` splat matches `.+`, which is necessary for what I'm doing - I've definitely rtfm, doesn't seem to mention it, so maybe it's not possible...

Answer (score 7):

Suppose you have this url: `/api/readFile/c:/a/a.txt`

If you want `req.params.path` to be `c:`:

```
'/api/readFile/:path*
```

If you want `req.params.path` to be `c:/a/a.txt`:

```
'/api/readFile/:path([^/]*)'
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's the current way I'm solving this problem, it doesn't appear that express supports any number of splat params with an optional named param:

```
app.all(/\/path\/([^\/]+)\/?(.+)?/,function(req,res,next){
  // Note: this is all hacked together because express does not appear to support optional splats.
  var params = req.params[1] ? [req.params[1]] : [],
      name = req.params[0];
  if(!params.length){
    // do something when there is no splat
  } else {
    // do something with splat
  }
});
```

I'd love to have this use named params for readability and consistency - if another answer surfaces that allows this I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1):

To have any trailing path to end up in a named param you can add parentheses to the asterisk;

```
router.get('/path/:trailing(*)?', function(req, res, next) {
  console.log(req.params.trailing);
  // ...
});
```

This for `/path/level1` would have the `trailing` param set to `level1`, and for `/path/level1/level2/level3` to `level1/level2/level3`.

Answer (score 0):

The above solutions using optional doesn't work in Express 4. And I tried couple of ways using search patterns, but not working either. And then I found this method and seems fired for unlimited nested path, http://expressjs.com/api.html#router

```
// this will only be invoked if the path starts with /bar from the mount point
router.use('/bar', function(req, res, next) {
  // ... maybe some additional /bar logging ...

  // to get the url after bar, you can try
  var filepath = req.originalUrl.replace(req.baseUrl, "");

  next();
});
```

It's match all /bar, /bar/z, /bar/a/b/c etc. And after that, you can read req.originalUrl, since params are not filled, ex. you can try compare baseUrl and originalUrl to get the remaining path.

Answer (score 0):

I got around this problem by using a combination of a middleware that add trailing slashes to url and `router.get('/bar/*?', ...`, which will pick up everything after `/bar/`, and return `undefined` if it is just `/bar/`. If the visitor asked for `/bar`, the `express-slash` middleware will add a slash to the request and turns the request into `/bar/`.