# Express.js route parameter with slashes

Tags: node.js, express

I have an application which serves file listings.

The application must respond to following routes:

```
/company/:id
/company/:id/dir
/company/:id/dir/dir
```

Here `/company/:id` is a route with no `path` specified e.g a `root` directory. I was thinking for something like `app.get('/company/:id/:path', ...` which obviously doesn't work.

How can I define a route which responds to all of the examples?

Comment: `/company/:id/*` does this work?

Comment: Same as: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10020099/express-js-routing-optional-spat-param/14481168 ?

Comment: @Andreas Hultgren seems so, flagged.

Comment: I disagree with the duplicate because https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10020099/express-js-routing-optional-splat-param is a subset of this for an optional splat. This one does not talk about optional, just the splat part.

Answer (score 87, accepted):

Use `/company/:id*` (note trailing asterisk).

Full example

```
var express = require('express')();

express.use(express.router);

express.get('/company/:id*', function(req, res, next) {
    res.json({
        id: req.params['id'],
        path: req.params[0]
    });    
});

express.listen(8080);
```

Comment: Or `/company/:id*` (without the slash).

Comment: @robertklep perfect, that handles all cases

Comment: The route parameters is { '0': 'adfadf/fasdfa', slug: 'aaaa' } when I request /aaaa/adfadf/fasdfa . i don't know where the key '0' come from

Comment: @NhưLàMơ `:id*` turns params into an array. So the :slug part is given the "slug" named property (assuming your path is `/:slug*`) in the params object, and then the 0th index is the rest of the matched part of the path.