# Node.js+express+mongodb handling two http get requests fired almost at the same time

Tags: node.js, express

I have a node.js+express+mongo DB app where,

```
app.get('/test/:testString', function (req, res) {
     console.log('req.params.testString: %s ', req.params.testString);
     ... insert to a collection....
```

from my client side, I fired two http get almost at the same time. I thought there should be two console.log print out for these two requests. However, strangely, only the second request's log shows and only the second request goes thru the collection insertion. On my server side terminal, I can see two http get requests arrived. Any idea?

Regards
Hammer

More:@CFrei @ Peter

I think I know the cause. I have http://www.google.com in my testString. If I remove '//' and '/', then I can see the log printed out. I have already used NSUTF8StringEncoding in my native firing of http get. Any special handling need to be added on express side?

Comment: You're right, should not happen and normally does not. What exactly do you return here? If you return the _id of your collection, then it would not be possible to send two requests without getting any trace of the second (or first).

Comment: I think this one helps to solve the problem "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16829803/express-js-route-parameter-with-slashes"

Answer (score 1):

If the client is a browser my first guess would be browser connection management interfering. Try using `curl` on the command line instead to test.

Comment: Sounds like you need to urlencode your url in the app before making your requests

Comment: this works http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16829803/express-js-route-parameter-with-slashes