# How to use parameters containing a slash character?

Tags: javascript, regex, node.js, express, routes

My MongoDB keys in `person` collection are like this:

```
TWITTER/12345678
GOOGLE/34567890
TWITTER/45678901
...
```

I define `getPersonByKey` route this way:

```
router.route('/getPersonByKey/:providerKey/:personKey').
  get(function(req, res) { // get person by key
    var key = req.params.providerKey + '/' + req.params.personKey;
    // ...
  }
);
```

Of course I'd prefer to be able to write something like this:

```
router.route('/getPersonByKey/:key').
  get(function(req, res) { // get person by key
    var key = req.params.key;
    // ...
  }
);
```

But this doesn't work, since `GET http://localhost/getPersonByKey/TWITTER/12345678` of course results in a 404, since the parameter with the slash is interpreted as two distinct parameters...
Any idea?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/16829803/438992, http://stackoverflow.com/q/10020099/438992?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Express internally uses [path-to-regexp](https://github.com/pillarjs/path-to-regexp) to do path matching.

As explained in the [documentation](https://github.com/pillarjs/path-to-regexp/blob/master/Readme.md), you can use a "Custom Match Parameter" by adding a regular expression wrapped in parenthesis after the parameter itself.

You can use the following path to get the result you need:

```
router.route('/getPersonByKey/:key([^/]+/[^/]+)').
  get(function(req, res) { // get person by key
    var key = req.params.key;
    // ...
  }
);
```

---

You can test and validate this or any other route [here](http://forbeslindesay.github.io/express-route-tester/).

Comment: Perfect. This is THE answer.

Comment: Perfect. Thank you for sharing this Amit. It's great that we can use RegEx.

Answer (score 8):

You can use this if your parameters has containing slashes in it

```
app.get('/getPersonByKey/:key(*)', function(req, res) { ... })
```

It works for me (at least in Express 4). In my case, I used parameters like `ABC1/12345/6789(10)`.
Hopefully this useful.

Answer (score 0):

`app.get('/getPersonByKey/:key(*)', function(req, res) { ... })`

This isn't working for me.

Swagger-ui will encode the path var before using it.
e.g. `article/2159` will become `article%2F2159`.
When going directly with curl, it will not get encoded. the slash will remain a slash instead of `%2F`. And then the route is not matched.

Update: I'm on fastify. On express 4.X this works correctly.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).