# Storing the URL directory in a variable in Node/Express

Tags: node.js, express

The following gives the output of the url/id.

```
app.get('/:id', function(req, res) {
   res.send('with slash' + req.params.id);
});
```

However, when I'm dealing with multiple slashes in the URL, I'm unable to get the id. For example, I want url/id1/id2/etc.../id. What should I put in place of the /:id for this?

Comment: So do you mean that you're trying to access a parameter *after* a parameter whose value should contain a forward slash (`/`)? E.g. in `/foo/bar/123`, you want `foo/bar` separately and `123` separately?

Comment: If so, does this answer your question? [*Express.js route parameter with slashes*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16829803/996081)

Comment: @cbr Yes, it should be able to handle `/foo/bar/123` or `/foo/bar/foo/bar/123`, and provide 123 separately and the other part separately.

Comment: @cbr Yes, it does answer my question... thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use multiple parameters in your URL.

```
/:id1/:id2
```