# Express.js app with multi-language routes

Tags: node.js, express, routes, url-routing, multilingual

I'm very new to `Node.js` and `Express.js` development and I'm looking for a simple and easy solution for creating multi language routes using `i18n` module.

I would like to achieve that urls in my app look like this:

www.myapp.com/**en**/about

www.myapp.com/**de**/about

www.myapp.com/**fr**/about

Than I would like to get the language as a string from url and sand it to the view as a variable. Like so:

```
app.get("/:lang/about",function(req,res){
    res.render("about",{language: lang}); 
});
```

The default language would be English - en.
Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `req.params` to get the URL parameters. You can make lang an [optional](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29549148/7317954) parameter, then set it to "en" if it is undefined. This will default it to english if the user load `/about` with no language specified.

```
app.get("/:lang*?/about",function(req,res){
    var lang = req.params.lang;
    if (lang === undefined) {
        lang = "en"
    }

    res.render("about",{language: lang}); 
});
```